# Spinned Cursor during ajax file uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, file-upload

I love stackoverflow, please help me again))

I used MiltiFile JQuery upload plugin, made commit on Staging and customer said me:

[image: Angry customer]

I really don't know is it a 'standard' behavior, because in Firefox the cursor is normal.
Okay, move forward.

I know that you will forward me to 'other cool plugin: swf.. or uploadify' BUT I thinking about some 'hack':

```
function SendFile() {
  $("#upload_ajax_image_submit").click();
  $('body').css("cursor", "pointer")
}
```

It's funny, it's work! Cursor is Pointer, and I not see the spinner Cursor now!
Okay, but we need standard cursor, not pointer.. Hmm.. Where are you?.. cursor "default"?
The problem is that "default" cursor is that 'spinned' cursor with which I struggle.

Any ideas?
Some technical information:
[Ubuntu, Google Chrome]

```
- form_for "upload_ajax_image", :url => upload_ajax_image_path, :format => 'js', :remote => true, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "upload_ajax_image"} do |f|

  = file_field_tag "attachment[attached]", :id=>"attachment_attached", :name => "attachment[attached][]", :accept => "bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png", :maxlength => "200", :multiple => true
  = f.submit "Send", :style=>"display:none"
```

Any Ideas = +100500 from me!